# How to grab the event when we drop the pegman on any marker in the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I need to grab the event if a user drags and then drop the pegman on a marker which is there on the map. How to do this?

Comment: You don't drop the pegman on a marker, you drop it on the map.

Comment: @Marcelo yes... I meant that i wanted to open the street view corresponding to the marker lats and long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the pegman's location manually, as it is done in [**this example**](http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_streetview_search.html):

The short code version is like this:

```
var G = google.maps;

var svpOptions = {
//      navigationControl: false,
//      addressControl: false,
//      linksControl: false,
        addressControlOptions: {
            style: { 
              border: '1px solid white', 
              backgroundColor: 'black',
              font: 'normal 10px verdana',
              color: 'white'
            }
        }
    };

    var latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(45.0, -90.0);
    svpContainer = document.getElementById('svpDiv');
    var svp = new G.StreetViewPanorama(svpContainer,svpOptions);
    svp.setPosition(latlon);
```